# Is it possible to create a WinForms Data Source from an internal class?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, visual-studio-2005

Is there a way to create a `System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource` from an internal class? Or would I have to make the class public?

When the class is internal, it does not appear in the *Add New Data Source* wizard in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, `internal` classes aren't visible outside of their assembly. This includes the assemblies used to drive the *Add New Data Source* wizard.

You *can* do what you describe if you write the code for it - and if you return the internal class as a reference with a public interface type.

```
public voide BindingSource GetMyBindingSource()
{
    return new MyInternalBindingSource();
}
```

Comment: could always keep the target class public while building then switch visibility to internal before building\releasing.

Comment: True, but then the code you release isn't the code you tested, and even changing class visibility can be the source of bugs.